# How to get started with CA agile rally automation

Tags: vba, web-services, rally, agile

I'm very eager to know how to automate agile rally without accessibg it from web site. Do we have any table or data bases for rally? Like Quality center (QC) . Can I automate it through VBA ? Do we have any connection string or libraries to make the automation feasible?

Comment: You need to be much more specific about what you are asking.  Questions such as "how do I code?" are not going to accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great Web Services API on top of Agile Central for doing these sorts of things, but not direct DB access.  There are toolkits for accessing them in a bunch of different languages- java, .net, node, etc.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

There is also an Excel Add-In which you could then manipulate with VBA if that's more of your thing...

Comment: don't think the excel addin can be manipulated from VBA, see here - https://communities.ca.com/thread/241766005

Answer (score 0):

Yep there's loads of info out there, what is it you need to do.. I do most of my updating via the command line there are a few aps worth looking into with npm just run a search on [rally](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=rally). If you need integration with git or Jenkins for example take a look at the [Agile central connectors](https://help.rallydev.com/connectors).. The QC con is [here](https://help.rallydev.com/rally-connector-quality-center).. Let us know how you get on..